# Paginate Issue Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-paginate

Was wondering if someone could check this out and let me know what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to use paginate on a database query and render it in my view.

Is my DB query incorrect? I was following the docs to create it. Also read that I needed to remove `->get()` when using paginate.

This is what is giving the error on my view: `{{$item->paginate(4)}}`, same happens if I use `{{$item->links(4)}}`

Everything renders fine if I remove paginate from the query in the controller..?

Here is what I'm working with.

**Controller:**

```
        public function index()
{
   // $news = DB::table('news')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(4);
    $news = DB::table('news')->select('id','title','description','listing_image','created_at','updated_at')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(4);
    return view('news.index',compact('news'));
}
```

**View:** (*Getting error: Call to undefined method stdClass::paginate()*)

```
@if ($news->count())
@foreach($news as $item)
...html
 @if ($item->listing_image)
...more html

    @else
    @endif 

... more html

@endforeach

{{$item->paginate(4)}}

@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change {{$item->paginate(4)}} to {{ $news->links() }}